# How to plot and solve the numerical solution of a integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have a integro-differential equation of the form 
$y'(t) =  - \int_0^t {y(t_1 )} e^{t_1  - t} dt_1,  {\rm{ t}} \in {\rm{[0,10], y(0) = 1}}$

My code is:

```
f[t_Real] := NIntegrate[y[t1]*Exp[t1-t], {t1, 0, t}];

solution1=NDSolve[{D[y[t], t]==-f[t], y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. solution1], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But this simply outputs the error:

> NIntegrate::nlim: t1 = t is not a valid limit of integration.

Comment: *Mathematica* can't directly handle integro-differential equations. Try converting it to an ODE, before feeding it to `NDSolve[]`.

Comment: I fixed some syntax errors in your code.  Also I do not get the same error.  I get `NIntegrate::inumr` (because of the symbolic `y[t1]` in the integral.  You probably had a hidden definition `f[t_] := NIntegrate[..]` that you had not cleared.  It's a good idea to restart the kernel and retry your code before posting.

Answer (score 18):

This integral equation is solvable using the [`LaplaceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LaplaceTransform.html) technique:

```
Clear[s, t];
eqn = y'[t] == -Integrate[y[t1] Exp[t1 - t], {t1, 0, t}]

LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s]

(*
==> 
s LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s] - y[0] == -(
  LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s]/(1 + s))
*)

Solve[%, LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s]]

(*
==> {{LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s] -> ((1 + s) y[0])/(
   1 + s + s^2)}}
*)

InverseLaplaceTransform[%, s, t]

(*
==> {{y[t] -> (
   E^(-t/2) (Sqrt[3] Cos[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] + Sin[(Sqrt[3] t)/2]) y[0])/
   Sqrt[3]}}
*)

ySolution[t_] = y[t] /. First[%] /. y[0] -> 1

(*
==> (E^(-t/
  2) (Sqrt[3] Cos[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] + Sin[(Sqrt[3] t)/2]))/Sqrt[3]
*)

Plot[ySolution[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Thank you. But I need the numerical solution of the integro-differential equation.

Comment: ...@user, Jens gave you a closed form solution, which is a bit more useful. Why do you still need a numerical solution? Unless... what you posted is in fact not your *actual problem*.

Comment: Thank you very much! I want to compare the difference the numerical and exact solution of the integro-differential equation.

Comment: @user7260 If you use [this package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4738/) for Laplace inversion, then you can get a semi-numerical solution.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably what [@Guess who it is.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) had in mind in the comment posted under the question.

```
solution1 = NDSolve[{
    D[y[t], t] == -Exp[-t] f0[t], y[0] == 1,
    f0'[t] == y[t]*Exp[t], f0[0] == 0},
   y[t], {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. solution1], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comparison with [Jens's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens) exact solution and how well the combined `PrecisionGoal`/`AccuracyGoal` is satisfied:

```
jsol = (E^(-t/2) (Sqrt[3] Cos[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] + Sin[(Sqrt[3] t)/2])) / Sqrt[3];
Plot[Evaluate[{y[t] - jsol /. solution1,
      {1, -1} (10^-(MachinePrecision/2.) + 10^-(MachinePrecision/2.) jsol)} // Flatten],
 {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]