# Recursive Integration

Tags: integral-equations

I'd like to evaluate the following recursive integration using *Mathematica*

$$
\ M(T) = \int_0^T\int_0^\infty e^{-\delta s}g(x,s)dxds\ +\int_0^T e^{-\delta s}f(s)M(T-s)ds\,
$$

where $g(x,s)$ and $f(s)$ are statistical probability density functions.
Since it's a recursive function, the initial condition is given by $M(0) = 0$.

For simplicity we can assume $f(s)$ to be an exponential PDF and $g(x,s)$ to be a Farlie–Gumbel–Morgenstern Copula PDF.

I am not interested in the closed form solution of $M(T)$, rather I am interested only in its numerical answer. This is what I've tried so far:

```
FGMExpExp = Exp[-2 (s + 10 x)] (36. - 18. Exp[s] + Exp[10 x] (-18.  + 19. Exp[s]));
Delta = 0.04; a = 10; b = 1; 
M[0] = 0; (* Initial Condition *)

Mu[T_] := Mu[T] = NIntegrate[Exp[-Delta*s]*x FGMExpExp, {x, 0, 1.05}, {s, 0, T}] + 
    NIntegrate[b Exp[-(Delta + b)*(T - s)] Mu[s], {s,0, T}]   (* Defining the integration *)
Mu[1] (* The quantity we are interested in. Will change T=1 to T=5 later *)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a simple example, we can let T=1 (evaluating the value of M after 1 year) and delta = 0.04.

Comment: ...this looks more like an integral equation.

Comment: @J.M. It's an integral equation with the previous values of M being used in calculating its future value.

Comment: Right, so a delay integral equation (in complete analogy to a DDE). Maybe you can try reformulating this as a DDE so you can use `NDSolve[]`?

Comment: Thanks @J.M.
Following your guide on delay integral equation, I found that the equation I am working on is quite similar to a Volterra equation of the 2nd kind. Please correct me if I am wrong, because I am from mathematical finance background and my physics knowledge can be assumed to be 0. Hence I don't fully understand the MMA Help section on Volterra. Is the LotkaVolterra functions in MMA made to calculate the M(T) or its differential form?

Comment: You don't need an initial condition here - it follows from your equation that $M(0)=0$, unless $M$ has some special kind of singularities.

Comment: Related question: [Solving a Volterra integral equation numerically](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4677/245)

Comment: @Jens Indeed. I completely missed that one. Perhaps because I generally tend to ignore most math-related questions. But that one is interesting. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*I am not interested in the closed form solution of M(T)* - and that's a great pity, since your equation can be solved exactly by using Laplace transform - for the numbers you have, and in the general case you can go a long way using the same approach.

#### Analytical solution

Applying Laplace transform to both sides of your equation, 
$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-p T}f(T)dT$, you get

$$\mu(p) = \int_{0}^{\infty}dT\int_{0}^{T}ds\, e^{-\delta s - p t}\tilde{g}(s)+\int_{0}^{\infty}dT\int{0}^{T}ds\, e^{-\delta s - p t}f(s)M(T-s)$$

where $\mu(p)$ is the Laplace transform of $M(T)$, and $\tilde{g}(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}  g(x,s)dx$. Now we can change the order of integrations as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}dT\int_{0}^{T}ds \rightarrow  \int_{0}^{\infty}ds\int_{s}^{\infty}dT$$

assuming, of course, decent behavior of our functions. Your equation then can be rewritten as

$$\mu(p) = \frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{\infty}ds\, e^{-(p+\delta)s}\tilde{g}(s)+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\delta s}f(s)ds\int_{s}^{\infty}M(T-s)e^{-p T}dT$$

In the last integral, you can shift the integration variable as $T^\prime = T-s $, which will lead for it to $\mu(p)F(p+\delta)$, where `F` is a Laplace transform for `f`:

$$F(q) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-q s}f(s)ds$$.

The final form for an equation for $\mu(p)$ is then

$$\mu(p) = \frac{1}{p} G(p+\delta) + \mu(p) F(p+\delta)$$

where $G$ is a Laplace transform of $\tilde{g}$, and I repeat the definition of $F$ for consistency:

$$F(q) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-q s}f(s)ds,\ G(q) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-q s}\tilde{g}(s)ds$$

The solution for this simple algebraic equation is:

$$\mu(p) = \frac{G(p+\delta)}{p(1- F(p+\delta))}$$

This is all there is to it, you just have to invert the Laplace transform.

In practice, if the analytical form of the inverse is hard to get, you can note that here you have a product of 3 functions $1/p$, $G(p+\delta)$, and $1/(1-F(p+\delta))$, for which it is much easier to get the inverses (we actually know them for the first two, only the last one may be a bit problematic). Then, you can use the property of Laplace transform that product in `p`-space translates into contraction $\int_{0}^{T}dtf(t)g(T-t)$ in `T`-space. But in your particular example, this is not needed.

#### Computation and numerics

Clearing some variables:

```
ClearAll[f,g,a,b,delta,gintx,s,p,mL,fL,mAn,mnum]
```

We first define your `g` function as

```
g[x_, s_] := Exp[-2 (s + 10 x)] (36. - 18. Exp[s] + Exp[10 x] (-18. + 19. Exp[s]))
```

It turns out to be quite nice:

```
gintx[s_] = Integrate[g[x, s], {x, 0, Infinity}]

(* 1. E^-s *)
```

where `gintx` is what I denoted as $\tilde{g}$ before. Now, its Laplace transform is trivial:

```
gl[p_]=LaplaceTransform[gintx[s],s,p]

(* 1./(1+p) *)
```

Defining your function `f`:

```
f[s_, a_, b_] := a*Exp[-b*s]
```

This one also has a trivial Laplace transform:

```
fL[p_, a_, b_] = LaplaceTransform[f[s, a, b], s, p]

(* a/(b + p) *)
```

Defining the final function for $\mu(p)$ according to the formula:

```
ClearAll[mL];
mL[p_, a_, b_, delta_] = gl[p + delta]/(p*(1 - fL[p + delta, a, b]))

(* 1./(p (1 + delta + p) (1 - a/(b + delta + p))) *)
```

Finally,finding analytical solution by inverting the Laplace transform:

```
mAn[t_, a_, b_, delta_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[mL[p, a, b, delta], p, t]

(* 
   1. (( b + delta)/((1 + delta) (-a + b + delta)) + 
   ((-1 + b) E^(-(1 + delta) t))/((1 + a - b) (1 + delta)) + 
  ( a E^(-(-a + b + delta) t))/((1 + a - b) (a - b - delta)))
*)
```

Well, that's it for your example. Here is how we can check: define a numerical function by using your original integral equation, where however we will use the analytical solution on the r.h.s. We can then compare this to the analytical solution itself. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[mnum];
mnum[t_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, delta_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-delta*s]*gintx[s], {s, 0, t}] + 
    NIntegrate[ Exp[-delta*s]*f[s, a, b]*mAn[t - s, a, b, delta], {s, 0, t}]
```

This is an exact codification of the original equation. Let's test this:

```
Plot[(mnum[t, 2, 1, 0.04] - mAn[t, 2, 1, 0.04]), {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

This looks pretty good to me.

#### Remarks

I went through all this because I wanted to reinforce the point I repeatedly am trying to make: Mathematica is many times more powerful when used as a tool we want to direct, rather than when one expects out of the box solutions for all problems - that won't happen.

Note that because we are able here to go quite a long way analytically, we have a much better insight and preparation for possible numerical implementation, for example when functions won't be so nice.

Comment: @rm-rf I usually ignore questions of this sort, but today I am in a strange, a little nostalgic mood.

Comment: Hold on then... let me post my difficult questions like this :D

Comment: @rm-rf Oh boy...No!!!  :-)

Comment: I'd give it 2 upvotes, if I could.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! Such a comment is especially great to receive when it comes from someone with your background and experience. These days I don't get a lot of chances to get into some math, so I thoroughly enjoyed this question.

Comment: I did notice you were having too much fun.

Comment: This reminded me of another related question: [How to plot and solve the numerical solution of a integro-differential equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24626/245)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Well, there is never too much, on a good Saturday night :-)

Comment: @Jens Missed that one too. Good stuff.

Comment: This is quite nice. :) I wonder when *Mathematica* will finally have built-in support for integral equations...

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. Re: support for integral equations - yes, that's a very good question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful response guys. I learnt a lot today, not just the Mathematica programming part but also on Laplace transform.
I tried to vote for the answer provided by Leonid Shifrin, but my reputation doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: @SNMRamli Was glad to help. This was a nice prolem. Re:rep -  it will come very soon if you stay on the site. And you can still accept answers, I am sure (but do so of course only if you feel that the answer does answer your question). Generally, it is a good idea to read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq), if you have not already done so.

Comment: @Leonid, right you are. Me, I was managing my online investments. Following the well known dictum, "If you can't e-trade on a Saturday night, you'll never e-trade at all".

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am sure that will pay off. My life is easier: no investments - no problems :-)

Comment: Wasn't serious. Just availing myself of a convenient rhyme, variations of which come in different levels of profanity, e.g.[here](http://www.theweebsite.com/bawdysongs/songs/ball_of_ballynoor.html) or [here](http://www.angelfire.com/ak/abbeyvsu/songsheetvirgins.htm) or [here](http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/m/misc/the_ball_of_kerrymiur_tab.htm). And they go downhill from there.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau lol :-). The links are cool.