# Integro-differential equation with double integral

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I am looking at the following variation of a integro-differential, with `y[0]=1`.
The output is not great, any solutions to this?

```
Clear[s, t, J, w];
J[w_] := 1/(2 + w^2)
eqn = y'[t] == -Integrate[y[t1] J[w] Exp[I (0.1 - w) (t1 - t)], {w, 0, ∞}, {t1, 0,t}] 

LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s] 

InverseLaplaceTransform[%, s, t] 

ySol[t_] = y[t] /. First[%] /. y[0] -> 1

Plot[ySol[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

---

### Update:

I received some feedback from a Wolfram Support Engineer regarding this question — it appears that current versions of *Mathematica* are unable to solve this sort of  integro-differential equations. Hopefully we will be able to see better  implementations and future versions can crack this sort of equations.

Comment: I guess you're trying to use the method I posted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24628/245), but the first thing one needs to correct then is that you have to say `Solve[%, LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s]]` before doing `InverseLaplaceTransform[%, s, t]`. That's not the *real* problem, though. Since you have two integrals, the solution would involve two Laplace transforms. Note that the `w` integral is itself a Laplace transform integral.

Comment: That's exactly right, this prob. is an extension of the earlier one, however you may note that the integrand involving J(w) can be sorted out at the earlier stage,  and then you ony have to deal with one laplace transform?

Comment: Come to think of it, I may not be right as the inner inregrant is dependent on y....

Comment: Yes, it's not so simple. One can simplify things with a translation of the `t` variables, but I'm out of time for today.

Comment: I get this output: "Unable to prove that integration limits {0,t} are real. Adding \
assumptions may help"

Comment: As a note, you do not need to nest `Integrate`, it accepts multiple limits. See the third form in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html).

Comment: Yes, there appears to be  improvement when I use the nest (edited the input now), but output  still not great. The bigger issue is what happens if there is no analytical solution, does NIntegrate needs to be used?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved with the Euler wavelets collocation method even in v.8 as follows

```
J[w_] := 1/(2 + w^2)
eqn = y'[
   t] == -Integrate[
    y[t1]  J[w]  Exp[I  (0.1 - w)  (t1 - t)], {w, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {t1, 0, t}]
```

First step. Let define `kernel` by integration on `w`

```
Integrate[
 Exp[I  (-1/10 + w)  dt]/(2 + w^2), {w, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {dt > 0}]

(*Out[]= (E^(-((I dt)/
  10)) (E^(-Sqrt[2] dt) \[Pi] + 
   I Sqrt[\[Pi]]
     MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, dt^2/2]))/(2 Sqrt[2])*)
```

Therefore

```
kernel[dt_] := (
 E^(-((I dt)/
   10)) (E^(-Sqrt[2] dt) \[Pi] + 
    I Sqrt[\[Pi]] MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, dt^2/2]))/(
 2 Sqrt[2])
```

Second step. Using `kernel` and substitution `t1 = t  s` we transform equation into Fredholm type

```
eqn = {y'[t] + t  NIntegrate[kernel[t - t  s] y[t  s], {s, 0, 1}] == 
   0, y[0] == 1};
```

Third step. Let define `y[t],D[y[t],t]` in the Euler wavelets base as

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2)   UE[m, 2^k  t - 2  n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <=
       t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]]; 
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; 
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; vary = Array[yy, {nn}]; 
y[t_] := vary . int1[t] + b0 ; dy[t_] := vary . Psi[t];
```

Final step. We define system of linear equations and solve it using `LinearSolve`

```
int2 = Table[
  t  NIntegrate[kernel[t - t  s] int1[t  s], {s, 0, 1}], {t, xcol}];

int0 = Table[t  NIntegrate[kernel[t - t  s], {s, 0, 1}], {t, xcol}];

eqs = Join[
   Table[vary . Psi[xcol[[i]]] + vary . int2[[i]] + b0  int0[[i]] == 
     0, {i, nn}], {y[0] == 1}];

var = Join[vary, {b0}]; {vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqs, var];

sol = LinearSolve[mat, -vec];
```

Visualization

```
rule = Table[var[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, Length[var]}]; Plot[
 Evaluate[ReIm[y[t] /. rule]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Interesting answer. Shouldn't the assumption be `dt<0` in the calculation of the `kernel`?

Comment: Please, pay attention that I used `Exp[I  (-1/10 + w)  dt]/(2 + w^2)` while in the `eqn` there is opposite sine in exp  as `J[w]  Exp[I  (0.1 - w)  (t1 - t)]`, therefore `dt=t-t1>0`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see it