# Solve discretized partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to numerically solve the following exemplary partial differential equation in discretized form. My question is more about the technique how one would implement this in Mathematica (not about a specific solution to the equation). The discretized equation reads as follows:

```
f[n+1,j]=f[n]+dt*(f[n,j]+j*(f[n,j+1]-f[n,j]))
```

where `n` is e.g. the n-th time step (`n*dt`) and `j` e.g. the j-th spatial step (`j*dx`).

Note that the initial function f[0,j] shall be given for all `j` (one can restrict it e.g. to the interval `j=[-100,100]`).

I tried to implement it with `FoldList[]` but fail to match the dimensions of my array. Is `FoldList[]` the wrong idea here or how could one do it?

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

In principle, I could also implement it with loops. However, I wonder whether this is the most performant way.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when `NDSolve` exists and can handle PDEs?

Comment: You are right, but as far as I know `NDSolve` won't apply to the equation I need to solve eventually (integro-differential equation).

Comment: You are probably right. Downloaded the .nb file, but where is the code?

Comment: @DisplayName Depending on where the integral is, you might still be able to use the method of lines to convert your integro-differential equation into a large set of ODEs, which `NDSolve` will handle better than your  implementation of Euler's method.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this already to transform it into a system of ODEs, but wasn't successful either. Maybe I need to think a little bit more about it.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid your question is a bit too board at the moment. Anyway, you may want to read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73974/1871).