# How to solve the differential equation with Duhamel's integral?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

How do I solve a differential equation with Duhamel's integral? I tried to solve it with `NDSolve`, but failed:

```
NDSolve[
   {0.01 - 6.25 x[t] + (1.2 Integrate[x'[t - τ]/Sqrt[τ], {τ, 0, t}])/10^7 == 16 x''[t], 
    x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
(* The input is returned unevaluated with a warning *)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`NDSolve` currently can't handle this kind of differential equation, `LaplaceTransform` is your friend. Since in this case inverse Laplace transform can't be done analytically by `InverseLaplaceTransform`, you need the help of [numerical Laplace inversion package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4738/) in addition:

```
eq = {0.01 - 6.25 x[t] + (1.2 Integrate[x'[t - τ]/Sqrt[τ], {τ, 0, t}])/10^7 == 16 x''[t]};
ic = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};

f[s_] = With[{l = LaplaceTransform}, 
   Solve[l[Rationalize[eq, 0], t, s] /. Rule @@@ ic, l[x[t], t, s]]][[1, 1, -1]]

sol = FunctionInterpolation[GWR[f, t], {t, $MachineEpsilon, 10}]

Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Remark:**

1. `eq` is `Rationalize`d because  the first argument of `GWR` should not contain approximate numbers.
2. `$MachineEpsilon` is chosen as the lower limit of `FunctionInterpolation` because `GWR` has some difficulty in calculating the inversion at $t=0$.

The figure of `sol` already looks nice, but if you're not satisfied with the current accuracy of `FunctionInterpolation`, you can improve it by adding derivatives of the expression to its first argument. This is mentioned in the **Scope** of the document of [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html) (Why it's not placed in a more conspicuous place?):

```
gwr[t_?NumericQ] := GWR[f, t]

solOrder3 = 
 FunctionInterpolation[
  D[gwr@t, {t, #}] & /@ Range[0, 3] // Evaluate, {t, $MachineEpsilon, 10}]

(* Notice Chop is necessary in this case *)
Plot[solOrder3[t] // Chop, {t, 0, 10}]

(* Error check *)
Plot[Subtract @@@ eq /. x -> solOrder3 // Abs // Evaluate, {t, ##}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All] & @@@ {{0., 0.002}, {0.002, 1}, {1, 
10}} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

**Related post:**

[How to plot and solve the numerical solution of a integro-differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24626/1871)

Comment: "if you're not satisfied with the current accuracy of `FunctionInterpolation`, you can improve it by adding derivatives of the expression to its first argument" - right, this is why Hermite interpolation is a good idea for approximating analytic functions; the more information you have, (hopefully) the better your approximant is. (This is also probably why Michael's solution was more accurate than your previous one, since the resulting `InterpolatingFunction[]` has derivative information.)

Comment: You could use the properties of the Laplace transforms of derivatives to create the higher order `solOrder3` instead of numeric differentiation.  It will be faster.  You could also use the ODE to solve for the higher order derivatives, since, at the initial condition, the integration term is zero.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Er…sorry, but I just can't figure out how to calculate the n-th derivative at $t=0$ where $n>2$. $x''(0)$ can be obtained by `Solve[eq /. t -> 0, x''[0]]/. x[0] -> 0 (* => x''[0] == 0.000625 *)`, but when it comes to `D[eq, t]`, a $\frac{x'(0)}{\sqrt{t}}$ term involves in. One may argue that since $x'(0)=0$ so this term is (probably) zero at $t=0$, too, but when it comes to `D[eq, {t, 2}]`, a  $\frac{x''(0)}{\sqrt{t}}$ term involves in…

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I changed my model into a more sophisticated one, and  LaplaceTransform method seems cannot work. Is there some method to solve it? This is the question:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86244/how-to-get-this-numerical-solution-of-a-integro-differential-equation

Comment: I meet the same question with you, I also need to solve the question, and i find the answer have something wrong

Answer (score 10):

One can use Picard-type iteration to get the solution: Using an approximation to `x'[t]` (in the integral), we can integrate the ODE to obtain a new approximation.  Remarkably, it converges in just two steps.  My original thought was to step through the integration using the tools from [`tutorial/NDSolveStateData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) to build an interpolation of `x'[t]` at each step for use in the integration term; that proved too difficult to manage (or perhaps I had set it up in way that made it difficult).

The approximation of `x'[t]` is represented by `xp[t]`.  We start with the initial guess for it to be `xp[t] == 0.01 t`, which corresponds to extrapolating from the initial conditions (by inspection -- one might solve the ODE for `x''`). (Actually, starting with `xp[t] == 0` works nearly as well and makes the first iteration faster.)  We put the integration factor in separate black-box function `y0`.  Adding the dummy algebraic equation `y[t] == y0[t]` to the system helps with the accuracy.

```
ClearAll[xp, y0, t, x, y];

xp = 0.01 # &;
y0[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[xp[t - τ]/Sqrt[τ], {τ, 0, t}];

ode = 0.01 - 6.25 x[t] + 1.2 y0[t] / 10^7 == 16 x''[t];
dae = y[t] == y0[t];
ics = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};

{sol[10.]} = NDSolve[{ode, ics, dae}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
xp = x' /. sol[10.];  (* iterate with next approximation to x' *)
{sol["Final"]} = NDSolve[{ode, ics, dae}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Let's compare with the solution produced by the numerical Laplace method used by [xzczd's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) answer. In what follows, we'll use

```
sol["Laplace"] = x -> FunctionInterpolation[GWR[f, t], {t, $MachineEpsilon, 10}]
```

where `f` and `GWR` are as in the other answer.

The solutions are roughly the same:

```
Plot[{x[t] /. sol["Laplace"], x[t] /. sol["Final"]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can compare how well the solutions track the ODE. The main reason that the Laplace method appears much worse is due to `FunctionInterpolation`.  It does, however, appear to be a better approximation at small values of `t`.  The function `opODE` gives the residual of a given solution `sol` at time `t` of the OP's ODE, with `NIntegrate` in place of `Integrate`.

```
opODE[t_?NumericQ, sol_] := Hold[
   0.01 - 6.25 x[t] + (1.2 NIntegrate[x'[t - τ]/Sqrt[τ], {τ, 0, t}])/10^7 - 16 x''[t]
   ] /. sol // ReleaseHold;

GraphicsRow[
 Plot[{opODE[t, sol["Laplace"]], opODE[t, sol["Final"]]},
    {t, ##}, PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All
    ] & @@@ {{0., 0.001}, {0.001, 1}, {1, 10}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`NDSolve` is a better alternative to `FunctionInterpolation` for constructing an accurate interpolation.  Oddly the Laplace method shows a similar erratic behavior near `t == 0` as the `NDSolve`-iteration method.  The function `GWR` of the [numerical Laplace inversion package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4738/) needs the argument `t` to be numeric, but does not protect it with `?NumericQ`; hence the wrapper `gwr` below.  With this method of interpolation the numerical Laplace method seems comparable.

```
gwr[t_?NumericQ] := GWR[f, t];
{sol["Laplace"]} = NDSolve[{x[t] == gwr[t], y'[t] == 1, 
    y[$MachineEpsilon] == $MachineEpsilon}, 
   x, {t, $MachineEpsilon, 10}];

GraphicsRow[
 Plot[{opODE[t, sol["Laplace"]], opODE[t, sol["Final"]]},
    {t, ##}, PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All
    ] & @@@ {{0., 0.002}, {0.002, 1}, {1, 10}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Presumably `x -> gwr` (from @xzczd) produces a highly accurate solution, but it takes a long time to evaluate.  For instance,

```
opODE[0.01, x -> gwr] // AbsoluteTiming
opODE[9.95, x -> gwr] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {27.7618, -1.13159*10^-13 - 7.74942*10^-15 I}
  {35.6744, -1.36696*10^-15 - 6.18062*10^-26 I}
*)
```

Comment: Very interesting. BTW  the `dae = y[t] == y0[t];` line isn't necessary.

Comment: As to the accuracy part: it's possible to improve the accuracy of `FunctionInterpolation`, see the edit of my answer.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, that's what I meant at the end of my post, only I didn't take the time to investigate completely.  For me, without the `dae`, the first step taken by `NDSolve` is about `0.01` (as I recall) with a max. error of about `0.03`, so that the solution does not settle down as quickly. That's why I was showing the `{0., 0.002}` interval, where this method is a little shaky, why I included `dae`, and why I made it separate code that can be easily taken out of the system.

Comment: Oh, "Adding the dummy algebraic equation y[t] == y0[t] to the system helps with the accuracy." I missed this sentence, seems that I'm a little tired today 囧

Answer (score 3):

Answer from `Mathematica 11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)`

```
ieqn = 0.01 - 6.25*x[t] + 
1.2* Integrate[x'[t - s]/Sqrt[s], {s, 0, 10}]/10^7 == 16*x''[t];
ic = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};
sol = DSolve[{ieqn, ic}, x[t], t]
```

> $\{\{x(t)\to 0.0016\, -0.0016 \cos (0.625 t)\}\}$

```
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

MMA can solve [integro-differential](http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/symbolic-and-numeric-calculus/solve-an-integro-differential-equation.html) equations now.

---

**EDITED 10.07.2018:**

It seems that in MMA `11.3` `DSolve` **can't solve** and return **unevaluated**.Probably it's a bug(regression).

Comment: It's faster if you `Inactivate[.., Integrate]` first and activate it again after `DSolve[]`.

Comment: A awkward truth is, if one modify the second argument of `DSolve` i.e. the `x[t]` to `x`, `DSolve` will fail...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result with Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 10, 64 bit..  Suggestions?

Comment: @bbgodfrey. Probably it's related to my question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134445/solving-integro-differential-equation-with-dsolve-in-mma-11-0. I send e-mail to Wolfram Technical Support and them  patched the bug.
They did not predict that it would affect  to other equations,its regression.

Comment: How embarrassing.  I even answered 134445, but I had forgotten about it.  Thanks for reminding me.