# NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand `E^(-0.9τ1) DiracDelta[t-τ1] v[t-τ1] x[t-τ1]` has evaluated to non-numerical values "

Tags: differential-equations

I am facing an interesting situation over here. The aim is to solve a system of IVP having an integral over a delay range. Here is my try

```
beta = 0.0012;
lambda = 2;
d = .10;
alpha = 0.002;
a = 0.5;
p = 5.6 ;
k = 70;
b = 2;
c = 40;
m1 = 0.9;
m2 = 0.9;
q = 5.6;
sigma = .0005;

First[NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == lambda - d x[t] - beta x[t] v[t], x[t /; t <= 0] == 3,
    y'[t] == 
     beta *NIntegrate[
        Exp[-m1*τ1]*DiracDelta[t - τ1]*x[t - τ1]*
         v[t - τ1], {τ1, 0, Infinity}] - a y[t] - 
      alpha w[t] y[t], y[t /; t <= 0] == 6,
    z'[t] == a w[t] y[t] - b z[t], z[t /; t <= 0] == 3,
    v'[t] == 
     k NIntegrate[
        Exp[-m2*τ1]*DiracDelta[τ1]*y[t - τ1], {τ1,
          0, Infinity}] - p v[t], v[t /; t <= 0] == 149,
    w'[t] == c  z[t] - q w[t], y5[t /; t <= 0] == 1
    },
   {x, y, z, v, w},
   {t, 0, 20}]];
```

which gives this error,

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 0.9 E^(-0.9 [Tau]1) v[t-[Tau]1]
>   x[t-[Tau]1] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling
>   points in the region

I have no clue what is going on. Please assist.

Comment: "non-numerical values" comes from `NIntegrate` , change for `Integrate` if symbolic and not numerical. Somebody else should comment about the validity of `z[t /; t <= 0]` inside `DSolve`.

Comment: `NIntegrate` can't handle `DiracDelta` (at least currently), this is mentioned in **Possible Issues** of the document of `DiracDelta.`

Comment: @xzczd If we replace 'DiracDelta' by a 'Sin' or 'Cos', I am getting the same  error message.

Comment: Because `NDSolve` also has trouble in handling nonlinear delay integro-differential equations 囧. If the equation is linear, one can make use of `LaplaceTransform`([this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84893/1871) is a example). But as far as I can tell, no one has ever managed to resolve a nonlinear case in this site. [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78564/1871) is slightly related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem my solution is that I do not know whether it is correct.Maybe someone will correct  my solution.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
beta = 3/2500;
lambda = 2;
d = 1/10;
alpha = 1/500;
a = 1/2;
p = 28/5;
k = 70;
b = 2;
c = 40;
m1 = 9/10;
m2 = 9/10;
q = 28/5;
sigma = 1/2000;
```

I calculate first integral separate:

```
Integrate[Exp[-m1*τ1]*DiracDelta[t - τ1]*x[t - τ1]*
v[t - τ1], {τ1, 0, Infinity},GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `E^(-9 t/10) HeavisideTheta[t] v[0] x[0]`

The `[t /; t <= 0]` isn't necessary because it's no longer a delay DE.

Initial conditions are: `v[0]=149`, `x[0]=3` and assume that `HeavisideTheta[t]` is `Piecewise[{{0, t < 0}, {1, t > 0},{Infinity, t == 0}}]`(Yes I now is `"undefined"` at point `t=0' but it does not change anything) then:

```
 V[0] = 149;
 X[0] = 3;
 intY = E^(-9 t/10)*Piecewise[{{0, t < 0}, {1, t > 0},{Infinity, t == 0}}]*V[0]*X[0]
```

I calculate second integral:

```
  intV = Integrate[Exp[-m2*τ1]*DiracDelta[τ1]*y[t - τ1], {τ1, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

We have:

> `-(-1 + HeavisideTheta[0]) y[t]`

Assume that `Limit[HeavisideTheta[x], x -> 0]=1` then `intV=0`.

Or `HeavisideTheta[0]` is often taken to be `1/2` then `intV=y[t]/2`

```
  intV = 0;
  sol = 
  With[{ϵ = 10^-10}, 
  First[NDSolve[{x'[t] == lambda - d x[t] - beta x[t] v[t], 
  x[ϵ] == 3, 
  y'[t] == beta*intY - a y[t] - alpha w[t] y[t], 
  y[ϵ] == 6, z'[t] == a w[t] y[t] - b z[t], 
  z[ϵ] == 3, v'[t] == k*intV - p v[t], 
  v[ϵ] == 149, w'[t] == c z[t] - q w[t], 
  w[ϵ] == 1}, {x, y, z, v, w}, {t, ϵ, 
  20}]]];
```

Plots with assuming that: `intV=0`

```
  Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t], v[t], w[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "y[t]", "z[t]", "w[t]"}]
```

[image]

```
  Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t], v[t], w[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 
  20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 500}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "y[t]", "z[t]", "w[t]"}]
```

[image]

Space curve for: `{x[t],y[t],z[t]}`

```
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 20}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thickness[0.015]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"space curve"}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't expect the integration can be calculated symbolicly! … But why you assume `v[0]=1; x[0]=2`?

Comment: `HeavisideTheta[0]` is often taken to be `1/2`, although I believe there is not universal agreement about that (hence it being undefined in *M*).  That would make `intV` to be `y[t]/2`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ,Thanks .Improving the post.

Comment: @xzczd.Without this assumption NDSolve can't solve.Other numbers can be set up v[0]=?,x[0]=?. ? = Any number.

Comment: So there's no special meaning to assume the values? Then you don't need to assume, they're already given as the initial conditions: `V[0] = 149;
X[0] = 3;`. Also, the `WorkingPrecision` option can be taken away, and the `[t /; t <= ϵ]` isn't necessary because it's no longer a delay DE :)

Comment: @xzczd.Yes You are right,my mistaken.

Comment: @I_Mariusz Thanks for your efforts. How can I plot space curves `x[t]` vs `y[t]` vs `z[t]`?

Comment: @MMM. Use :`ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thickness[0.015]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`