# How can I invert a Laplace transform numerically?

Tags: numerics, integral-transforms

I have a very complicated expression, which I want to transform using the inverse Laplace transform.  The built-in function `InverseLaplaceTransform` doesn't work. So, I would like to do it numerically. What are the best ways/packages to do that?

Function

```
fnm[s_, n_] := a1[s] y[s]^n + a2[s] y[s]^-n;
```

where `a1, a2, y` and `c2` are complicated functions of `s`. For example,

```
a1[s_] :=
  (kon (y[s]^m + y[s]^(2 L - m + 1))) /
    (c2[s] (y[s]^m + y[s]^(1 - m)) (y[s]^m  + y[s]^(2 L - m + 1)) + 
      u (1 - y[s]^2) (1 - y[s]^(2 L)));

y[s_] := 
  (s + 2 u + kon - (kon koff)/(s + koff) - 
    Sqrt[(s + 2 u + kon - (kon koff)/(s + koff))^2 - 4 u^2])/(2 u);

c2[s_] := (kon koff)/(s + koff);

a2[s_] := 
  (kon y[s] (y[s]^m + y[s]^(2 L - m + 1))) /
    (c2[s] (y[s]^m + y[s]^(1 - m)) (y[s]^m  + y[s]^(2 L - m + 1)) + 
      u (1 - y[s]^2) (1 - y[s]^(2 L)));
```

Comment: What happens if you simply write out the InverseLaplace integral with your integrand (function)?

Comment: I did [some work](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/quick-and-dirty-inversion/) on this; I really should find the time to implement the extended version of the algorithm there...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork there is no output. Mathematica is running and never stops.

Comment: What is `a2[s]`?  Why do you use an upper-case `L` which can conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names?  What can we assume about `u`, `m`, etc.?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork As I mentioned, `a2[s]` is another function of `s`. I will change `L` to `l`. `u,m,kon,koff` are variables, which I am going to plug-in later. (Is it possible to do after inversion?)

Comment: Many (many many) years ago I used a numerical package that is available in the Wolfram library: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/2691/

Comment: Also, you can try [this package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4738/) (BTW I've used the package in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84893/1871).)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of *v12.2*, `InverseLaplaceTransform` supports numeric Laplace inversion. In addition, there exist at least 6 *Mathematica* packages for numeric inverse Laplace transform. They're:

- [NumericalLaplaceInversion (`GWR`)](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4738/)
- [FixedTalbotNumericalLaplaceInversion (`FT`)](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/)
- [`inverseLaplaceHyperbolic`](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2019/04/12/laplace-transform-inversion-with-a-hyperbolic-contour/)
- [CME (`ILT`)](http://inverselaplace.org/)
- [NumericalInversion](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/2691/)
- [NLapInv](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4185/)

Currently I only have experience with the first 2 packages so I'll solve OP's problem only with `GWR` and `FT` in this answer. (I might add illustrations for other packages later. )

Since OP doesn't show the possible value of parameters, they'll be casually chosen as:

```
test[s_] = Block[{kon = 1, koff = 2, u = 3, L = 4, m = 5, n = 6}, fnm[s, n]];
```

### `InverseLaplaceTransform` solution

As mentioned above, this feature is added in *v12.2*:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[test[s], s, 10^-3.]
(* -0.983223 *)

With[{eps = 10^-3}, 
     Plot[InverseLaplaceTransform[test[s], s, N@t],
          {t, eps, 3 + eps}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> All]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Notice 3rd argument of `InverseLaplaceTransform` cannot be an exact number, or the numeric methods won't be invoked.

### `GWR` solution

The usage of `GWR` function has been explained clearly in **NumericalLaplaceInversionExample.nb** so I'd like not to repeat it here.

```
With[{eps = 10^-3.}, 
   rstGWR = Table[{t, GWR[test, t]}, {t, eps, 3 + eps, 1/25}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.546700, Null} *)

ListLinePlot[rstGWR, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### `FT` solution

The usage of `FT` function has been documented in **FixedTalbotNumericalLaplaceInversionExample.nb** so, once again, I'd like not to repeat.

```
With[{eps = 10^-3.}, 
   rstFT = Table[{t, FT[test, t]}, {t, eps, 3 + eps, 1/25}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.765505, Null} *)

ListLinePlot[rstFT, PlotRange -> All]
```

The result just looks the same as that of `GWR` so I'll omit it here. The only thing worth adding is, `FT` can give symbolic expression as output, and the output can even be `Compile`d **in some cases**, but sadly:

```
symbolicinversion = FT[test, t];

cf = Compile[t, #] &@symbolicinversion;

With[{eps = 10^-3.}, 
   rstFTcompiled = Table[{t, cf@t}, {t, eps, 3 + eps, 1/25}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.015624, Null} *)

ListLinePlot[rstFTcompiled, PlotRange -> {-1, 1/10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`test` isn't the case.

### `inverseLaplaceHyperbolic` trial

A quick test shows that, `inverseLaplaceHyperbolic` works as well on `test` except for very small `t`. (Yeah, similar to `rstFTcompiled`. ) The following is my trial. Feel free to point out if I've used the function in improper way.

```
With[{eps = 10^-3.}, 
   rstHyper = Table[{t, 
      inverseLaplaceHyperbolic[test[s], {s, t}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]}, {t, eps, 
      3 + eps, 1/25}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.557155, Null} *)
ListLinePlot[rstHyper, PlotRange -> {-1, 1/10}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

### `ILT` trial

A quick test shows that, `ILT` doesn't seem to work well on `test`. The following is my trial. Feel free to point out if I've used the function in improper way.

```
fneval = 250;
With[{eps = 10^-3}, 
   rstILT = {#, ILT[test, #, fneval]}\[Transpose] &@
     Range[eps, 3 + eps, 1/25]]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListLinePlot[rstILT, PlotRange -> {-1, 1/10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'd appreciate if someone tell me how to use the GWR method to solve the above mentioned problem with the parameter kon varying between 1 and 10. So, i need to find the solution as a function of time and kon. Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: @JoseOM Just check the documents of `Table` and `Interpolation`.

Comment: "`inverseLaplaceHyperbolic` works as well on test except for very small `t`. (Yeah, similar to `rstFTcompiled`.)" - not too surprised, both are very similar contour integral methods, except that the former uses a contour that is cheaper to evaluate.