# Mathematica 12 returns a "greater::nord" error when Mathematica 11 does not

Tags: integral-transforms

In the following code Talbot's method is made use of to invert Laplace's transforms.

```
FT[F_, t_, M_:32]:=
    Module[{np, r, S, theta, sigma},

    np = Max[M, $MachinePrecision];
    r = SetPrecision[2M/(5t), np];
    S = r theta (Cot[theta] + I);
    sigma = theta + (theta Cot[theta] - 1)Cot[theta];

    (r/M)Plus @@ Append[Table[Re[Exp[t S](1 + I sigma)F[S]],
            {theta, Pi/M, (M - 1)Pi/M, Pi/M}],
                (1/2) Exp[r t] F[r]]
    ]

f[t_] := Sin[Sqrt[t^3]]
F[s_] := LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]
F[s]
-((2 E^((2 s^3)/
  27) π (3^(1/3) s AiryAi[s^2/(3 3^(1/3))] + 
    3 AiryAiPrime[s^2/(3 3^(1/3))]))/(3 3^(2/3)))

Numerical inversion

ListLinePlot[Table[FT[F, t], {t, 1/100, 3 π, 1/10}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 3 π}]
Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 1275.8850200142971803611536794703+125.66370614359172953850573533118 I attempted.
Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 1263.5082252451525277160213296258+251.32741228718345907701147066236 I attempted.

etc.
```

However, when running the same code in Mathematica 11, no error is returned and a plot obtains.

The routine for Laplace inversion "FixedTalbotNumericalLaplaceInversion.m" is taken from Prof Valko at [Numerical Inversion of Laplace Transform with Multiple Precision Using the Complex Domain](https:////library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/) https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/

To have the full complement of the script in the same file, I simply inserted the inversion routine as soon as I got the error mentioned above in an attempt to make sense of what was wrong with Mathematica 12.

Is there any workaround available? Any input would be most welcome.

Kind regards,
FB

**New trial.**

I tried something that looks a bit crazy by adding  `/. t :> Hold[t]` as the last instruction of the Module as shown below.

```
FT[F_, t_, M_: 32] :=
     Module[{np, r, S, theta, sigma},
      np = Max[M, $MachinePrecision];
      r = SetPrecision[2 M/(5 t), np];
      S = r theta (Cot[theta] + I);
      sigma = theta + (theta Cot[theta] - 1) Cot[theta];
      (r/M) Plus @@ Append[Table[Re[Exp[t S] (1 + I sigma) F[S]],
                   {theta, Pi/M, (M - 1) Pi/M, Pi/M}],
                      (1/2) Exp[r t] F[r]] /. t :> Hold[t]
      ]
f[t_] := Sin[Sqrt[t^3]]
F[s_] := LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]
F[s]
-((2 E^((2 s^3)/
  27) π (3^(1/3) s AiryAi[s^2/(3 3^(1/3))] + 
    3 AiryAiPrime[s^2/(3 3^(1/3))]))/(3 3^(2/3)))

Numerical inversion

ListLinePlot[Table[FT[F, t], {t, 1/100, 3 π, 1/10}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 3 π}]

Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 1436.34273378008538223220463729378957+125.663706143591729538505735331180115 I attempted.
Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 1425.34858407586809615094260717379879+251.327412287183459077011470662360231 I attempted.
Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 1406.95000798586880344490258473825676+376.991118430775188615517205993540346 I attempted.
General::stop: Further output of Greater::nord will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

The errors are still there but now I get the correct plot!

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards

**Update**

It appears that the reason why the Laplace inversion routines (FT, GWR, etc) return the above errors seems to be that the Laplace transform is recomputed inside those routines.

As a case in point, here’s what happens with GWR:

```
f4[t_] := Sin[Sqrt[t^3]]
F4[s_] := LaplaceTransform[f4[t], t, s]
F4[s]
-((2 E^((2 s^3)/
  27) π (3^(1/3) s AiryAi[s^2/(3 3^(1/3))] + 
    3 AiryAiPrime[s^2/(3 3^(1/3))]))/(3 3^(2/3)))

Numerical inversion

ListLinePlot[Table[GWR[F4, t], {t, 1/100, 3 π, 1/10}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 3 π}]
NIntegrate::write: Tag Rational in 1/100 is Protected..
NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.01`67.2 cannot be used as an iterator.
```

The stack trace corresponding to this error shows what is happening:

[image]

That is, the contents of variable *t* has been substituted too early, and clearly the rational 1/100 cannot be used as an iterator.

If the above observation is correct, what can we do to avoid this early substitution?
Please advise.
Regards

Comment: Use: `F[s_] = LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]` not: `F[s_] := LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]`.

Comment: I had thought of this already. The error disappears in effect, but unfortunately you get nonsensical results. Maximum value to the order of 10^169 when it should be 1. Again, everything runs smoothly with Mma11.

Comment: In version 12.0, You can try to set `SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow"->False]`. In this way, we can turn off the prompt message.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, this instruction does not remove the greater::nord errors.  
I am more and more convinced that the problem in the above code is somehow related to the function F representing the Laplace transform and the way it gets dealt with in the Module FT. For if the transform is keyed in through a Function as is required by FT, everything seems to runs smoothly. I will go on experimenting in that direction. This behaviour is new to Mma 12 as it is not evinced in Mma 11.

Comment: With a mobile phone at hand I can not do much, but the problem of `F[s_]:=` can be boiled down to the following: `F[1+I]` causes the `nord` warning. As to the invalid result given by `F[s_]=`, I suggest comparing the expression of `F[s]` in _v11_ and _v12_ first.

Comment: @xzczd I have followed your piece of advice and compared the results obtained making use of `F[s_] = LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s]` both with Mma 11 and Mma 12. The two versions give exactly the same incorrect results as well as plots. In addition, I performed quite a few experiments. For most of the Laplace transforms to be numerically inverted the correct results are obtained either through using the above instruction or making use of a pure function. Therefore, the initial use as suggest by Abate and Valko’s  package should work. Unfortunately, this is not the case. Could be a bug after all.

Comment: The correct result can be obtained with [`GWR`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193565/1871) package when `F` is defined as `F[s_]=`. I've found that `FT` may fail in certain cases but never look into it. (The failure might be related to contour choosing, if I have to guess. )

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, `F` should be defined with `Set` i.e. it should be `F[s_]=...`. If you define it with `SetDelayed`(`:=`), things like `LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, 1+I]` will be generated in calculation, while the last argument of `LaplaceTransform` is always a symbol in the document. In other words, if you define `F` with `:=`, you will be making  use of an undocumented syntax, which is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: As to the question in the update, I can't test because the calculation is too slow, but  `ListLinePlot[Table[GWR[F4, t2], {t2, 1/100, 3 \[Pi], 1/10}], DataRange -> {0, 3 \[Pi]}]` may work. The underlying issue is, `Table` uses `Block` to localize `t`, while the `t` in `F` is not properly localized.