# Inverse Laplace in mathematica

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions, integral-transforms

I can't even get an inverse Laplace for this expression numerically in mathematica,
is there a way to inverse this equation below?

I have also tried to use fixt talbot package for a numerical calculation and it was not possible to get an answer. I also struggled with the options presented here, but I was not successful

[How can I invert a Laplace transform numerically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98737/how-can-i-invert-a-laplace-transform-numerically)

```
    1/s^(5/4) (0.0048093124845766414` + 0.02440766170480293` s^(1/4) + 
       0.012905621492995754` E^(-35.` s) s^(1/4) + 
       0.0032916706480934036` E^(0.7079967811634376` s) s^(1/4)
         Gamma[0.`, 35.70799678116344` s] - 
       0.0053059348427644286` Gamma[1.25`, 35.` s])
```

and

```
    InverseLaplaceTransform[  s^(5/4)/(0.0048093124845766414 +
    0.02440766170480293s^(1/4) + 0.012905621492995754 E^(-35. s) s^(1/4)
    +0.0032916706480934036 E^(0.7079967811634376 s) s^(1/4)Gamma[0, 35.70799678116344 s]
     - 0.0053059348427644286 Gamma[1.25, 35. s]), s, t]
```

Update:
The first one works in Mathematica version 13.1. but the second one still not.

I think because the inverse of some functions is conditional in this case, we get InverseLaplaceTransform [of something that is defined in some cases and undefined in others] printed after we excite the code.

Getting an answer is only possible if the basis of the variables is defined. I think that is the point, but it is only possible in version 13.1, not in the previous version.

Comment: Your question boils down to: How can I calculate the inverse Laplace transform of `Gamma[5/4,s]/s^(5/4)`. All other terms seem to be ok, see `Map[InverseLaplaceTransform[#,s,t]&, {s^(-5/4),s^(-1),Gamma[0,s]/s}]`. But I am a little confused by the fact that `InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[s]*Gamma[0,s]/s,s,t]` gives `1-EulerGamma+1/t-Log[s]` which still contains an `s`, in Version 12.3.

Comment: @user, that looks like an old bug that is now fixed; the correct answer `Log[1 + t]` is now returned.

Comment: With 13.1, I obtain for the `InverseLaplaceTransform` of the expression in the question, `0.0244077 + 0.00530593 t^(1/4) + 0.0129056 HeavisideTheta[-35. + t] - 
 0.00530593 t^0.25 HeavisideTheta[-35. + t] + 0.00329167 InverseLaplaceTransform[(E^(0.707997 s) Gamma[0., 35.708 s])/s, s, t]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Do I need to calculate the last term numerically? It's really hard for me to calculate something numerically in Matematica :(

Comment: Not sure.  Let's see what others, like @J.M., has to say.

Comment: I'll only note that `InverseLaplaceTransform[(E^(a s) Gamma[0, b s])/s, s, t]` evaluates, so you can plug appropriate values of `a` and `b` into the result of that expression.

Comment: @J.M. do you have any idea about the second one ? Its wierd :(

Comment: Are you not able to apply the workaround I hinted at?

Comment: @J.M. It works for the first, but not really for the second. I'll try to validate it in discrete to see if it works. Thanks in any way

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what exactly you're doing that has you ending up with incomplete gamma functions in the denominator...

Comment: @J.M. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41704/a-direct-numerical-method-for-determining-a-relaxation-function-from-a-known-cre?noredirect=1#comment81416_41704 you can see it here if its interesting for you.