# Fractional PDE with CaputoD

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve this fractional PDE

```
a=1/2;
sol = NDSolveValue[{CaputoD[y[t,x], {t, a}] == D[y[t,x],{x,2}], y[0,x] ==Sin[Pi x], {y[t,0]==0,y[t,1]==0}},
y, {t,0,0.2},{x,0,1}]
```

It works for the usual case $a=1$, but for $a=1/2$ e.g, it returns many errors:

`NDSolveValue, Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations`

`NDSolveValue, an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable`

`NDSolveValue, has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended`

`NDSolveValue, Repeated convergence test failure at t==0`

Maybe such syntax is not allowed by MMA, if this is the case, I'm looking for an idea to handle it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's simply because `NDSolve` cannot handle fractional differential equation at the moment. (Fractional derivative isn't even supported by *Mathematica* until *v13.1*! ) But luckily, as mentioned in [Summary of New Features in 13.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn131)
, `DSolve` can now solve Caputo fractional differential equations:

```
a = 1/2;
DSolve[{CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}], 
  y[0, x] == Sin[Pi x], {y[t, 0] == 0, y[t, 1] == 0}}, y, {t, x}]
(* {{y -> Function[{t, x}, E^(π^4 t) Erfc[π^2 Sqrt[t]] Sin[π x]]}} *)
```

Alternatively, we can solve it with `LaplaceTransform`:

```
a = 1/2;

{eq, ic, bc} = {CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}], 
   y[0, x] == Sin[Pi x], {y[t, 0] == 0, y[t, 1] == 0}};

tset = 
 LaplaceTransform[{eq, bc}, t, s] /. Rule @@ ic /. 
   HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a /. y -> (Y[#2] &)
(* {-(Sin[π x]/Sqrt[s]) + Sqrt[s] Y[x] == Y''[x], {Y[0] == 0, Y[1] == 0}} *)

tsol = DSolveValue[tset, Y[x], x]
(* Sin[π x]/((π^2 + Sqrt[s]) Sqrt[s]) *)

sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol, s, t]
(* E^(π^4 t) Erfc[π^2 Sqrt[t]] Sin[π x] *)
```

"But what if I insist on solving it numerically?" Then we can combine *method of lines* and the method for solving FODE [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271710/1871). I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for discretization in $x$ direction:

```
a = 1/2; t0 = 0; tend = 1/50; xL = 0; xR = 1;
{eq, ic, bc} = {CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}], 
   y[t0, x] == Sin[Pi x], {y[t, xL] == 0, y[t, xR] == 0}};
nt = 15; range = Range[0, nt - 1];
coef[x_] = c[x] /@ range;
poly[x_][t_] = coef[x] . t^range;
domaint = {t0, tend};
CGLGrid[xl_, xr_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
 1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(π Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)])
gridt = CGLGrid[##, nt] & @@ domaint;

nx = 25; domainx = {xL, xR};
difforder = 2;
gridx = Array[# &, nx, domainx];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)    
ptoofunc = pdetoode[y[t, x], t, gridx, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
{ode, odeic} = del /@ ptoofunc@{eq, ic};
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;
{approxode, approxic, approxbc} = {ode, odeic, odebc} /. y -> poly; // AbsoluteTiming

var = coef /@ gridx // Flatten;
sys = Flatten@{Table[approxode, {t, Rest@gridt}], Table[approxbc, {t, gridt}], 
    approxic};
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[sys, var];
csol = LinearSolve[marray, -N@barray];

Block[{c}, Evaluate@var = csol; 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Table[{t, x, poly[x][t]}, {x, gridx}] // Evaluate, {t, t0, tend}, 
   PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}]]~Show~
 Plot3D[sol, {t, t0, tend}, {x, xL, xR}]
```

[image]

Notice the `sol` is defined in 2nd code block above.

`poly[x][t]`s are lines in `t` direction at separate `x`s. You can of course build a continuous `InterpolatingFunction` from them for convenience:

```
nsol = Block[{c}, Evaluate@var = csol;
  ListInterpolation[Table[poly[x][t], {t, gridt}, {x, gridx}], {gridt, gridx}]]

DensityPlot[nsol[t, x], {t, t0, tend}, {x, xL, xR}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

We can see the solution is a bit noisy for small `t`, it's because we've used a rather sparse grid in `t` direction. You can increase `nt` for better numeric solution.

> **Remark**
>
> For larger `nt`, you may need to modify `N@barray` to something like
> `N[barray, 32]`.

We can also use the `` fdeivp` `` package in the linked post to solve the discretized FPDE. Since [`fdesolve`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271710/1871) is designed only for FDE system in the form $\mathcal{D}^\alpha y(x)=f(x,y(x))$, we need to discretize the FPDE in a slightly different way:

```
a = 1/2; t0 = 0; tend = 1/50; xL = 0; xR = 1;
{eq, ic, bc} = {CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}], 
                y[t0, x] == Sin[Pi x], {y[t, xL] == 0, y[t, xR] == 0}};

nx = 25; domainx = {xL, xR}; difforder = 2;
gridx = Array[# &, nx, domainx];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[y[t, x], t, gridx, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = del@ptoofunc@eq;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;

odebc = With[{sf = 0}, Map[sf # + CaputoD[#, {t, 1/2}] &, ptoofunc@bc, {2}]];
 
solve[eqn_, var_] := 
 LinearSolve[#2, -#1] & @@ CoefficientArrays[eqn // Flatten, var // Flatten]

iclst = solve[odeic, Outer[y[#][0] &, gridx]];
rhslst = solve[Flatten@{ode, odebc}, 
    Outer[CaputoD[y[#][t], {t, 1/2}] &, gridx]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.63153, Null} *)

scale = Evaluate@Rescale[#, domainx, {1, nx}] &;
  
rhsfunc = Function[{t, y}, #] &[
    rhslst /. y[i__][t] :> RuleCondition@Part[y, scale@i]]; // Quiet
(* Definition of fdesolve isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)    
nt = 15; 
sollst = fdesolve[a, rhsfunc, N[iclst, 100], tend, nt, Compiled -> False];

solfunc = ListInterpolation[sollst, {{0, tend}, domainx}];
```

Notice I've made use of arbitrary precision calculation by setting the precision of initial values to `100` with `N` and avoiding compiling with `Compiled -> False`, otherwise the error accumulation will be unbearable. You may need to set precision larger than `100` for larger `nt`.

The solution can be visualized with e.g.

```
ListPlot[sollst, DataRange -> domainx]~Show~
 Plot[Table[
    E^(π^4 t) Erfc[π^2 Sqrt[t]] Sin[π x], {t, 0, tend, tend/nt}] // 
   Evaluate, {x, xL, xR}]
```

[image]

or

```
ContourPlot[solfunc[t, x], {t, 0, tend}, {x, xL, xR}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: @xzczd what if there is no closed form for the solution/InverseLaplace transform?

Comment: @Migalobe Then you may want to read this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/271690/1871

Comment: @xzczd this is an ODE, would it work for a PDE? I was thinking abt the equation `CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}]+D[y[t, x], {x, 1}]` with same ic and bc. Maybe it can be done simply?

Comment: @Migalobe It'll work. The step is: 1. Discretize the PDE in x direction based on method of lines. 2. Use certain FODE solver to solve the FODE system. I won't say it's simple, though. See my update.

Comment: @Migalobe BTW, for your specific problem, you can still use the Laplace transform method. You just need numeric inverse Laplace transform for the last step. See this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193565/1871

Comment: `crule` not defined ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Oops, I forgot to remove it. (I used `Solve` rather than `LinearSolve` at beginning. ) Edited. Thx for pointing out.

Comment: @xzczd Many thanks! I thought about numerical inverse laplace, but i couldn't find it in my old version.

Comment: @xzczd I got a graph with just lines, did you delete something to interpolate as you got above?

Comment: @Migalobe The `sol` is defined in 2nd code block above.

Comment: @xzczd I meant how to show 2nd numerical solution as continuous graph

Comment: @Migalobe Just build a `InterpolatingFunction`. See my update.

Comment: @xzczd the methods fail for `CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}]+D[y[t, x], {x, 1}]` (1st one is not accurate and 2nd gives weird solutions)

Comment: @Migalobe Have you adjusted the parameters according to the notes above?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, nt, nx, and barray. I also noticed that if we increase nt we lose accuracy (especially, near 0). ListInterpolation with 1st order is ok with 1st method but the curve is not smooth.

Comment: @Migalobe How do you assess the accuracy?

Comment: @xzczd I tried bigger values for nt and got weird lines (weird graph). Also, I plotted the norm of the solution and got an oscillating curve near 0 (this issue is handled by InterpolationOrder->1, but I need a smooth curve in the plot)

Comment: @Migalobe If the method really fails, `InterpolationOrder->1` should not improve the result AFAIK. Can you be more specific? If it's too long for comment, consider posting a separate question to show your complete code sample.

Comment: @xzczd here we go: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/297818/63167