# Numerical solution to fractional PDE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, fractional-calculus

Following the idea [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271689/63167) by @xzczd, I tried:

```
a = 1/10; t0 = 0; tend = 1/50; xL = 0; xR = 1;
{eq, ic, bc} = {CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}], 
y[t0, x] == Sin[Pi x], {y[t, xL] == 0, y[t, xR] == 0}};
nt = 15; range = Range[0, nt - 1];
coef[x_] = c[x] /@ range;
poly[x_][t_] = coef[x] . t^range;
domaint = {t0, tend};
CGLGrid[xl_, xr_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(\[Pi] Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)])
gridt = CGLGrid[##, nt] & @@ domaint;
nx = 25; domainx = {xL, xR};
difforder = 2;
gridx = Array[# &, nx, domainx];
(*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post, please find it in the link above.*)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[y[t, x], t, gridx, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
{ode, odeic} = del /@ ptoofunc@{eq, ic};
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;
{approxode, approxic, approxbc} = {ode, odeic, odebc} /. 
y -> poly; // AbsoluteTiming
var = coef /@ gridx // Flatten;
sys = Flatten@{Table[approxode, {t, Rest@gridt}], 
Table[approxbc, {t, gridt}], approxic};
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[sys, var]; 
csol = LinearSolve[marray, -N[barray, 32]];
Block[{c}, Evaluate@var = csol;
ParametricPlot3D[
Table[{t, x, poly[x][t]}, {x, gridx}] // Evaluate, {t, t0, tend}, 
PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}]]
nsol = Block[{c}, Evaluate@var = csol;
ListInterpolation[Table[poly[x][t], {t, gridt}, {x, gridx}], {gridt, gridx}]];
```

The plot gives

[image]

Let's compare with the analytical solution

```
sol3 = DSolve[{CaputoD[y[t, x], {t, a}] == D[y[t, x], {x, 2}], 
y[0, x] == Sin[Pi x], {y[t, 0] == 0, y[t, 1] == 0}}, y, {t, x}];
g[t_] := Integrate[Evaluate[y[t, x] /. sol3[[1]]]^2, {x, 0, 1}]
```

The plot gives
Plot[{NIntegrate[nsol[t, x]^2, {x, 0, 1}], g[t]}, {t, t0, tend}]

[image]

My question is about the numerical issues in the above plot:

1. How to handle the **oscillation** near $0$?
2. How to get a **smooth** curve as in the analytical solution?

I tried to increase the number of points, e.g. `nt=25` and `nx=45`, but the plot of lines become very different (oscillating near `t=1/50`) and second plot improves but still oscillating

[image]
[image]

Comment: The problem is quite similar to this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10055/1871 Try `g[t_] = Integrate[Evaluate[y[t, x] /. sol3[[1]]]^2, {x, 0, 1}]; Plot[{NIntegrate[nsol[t, x]^2, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}], g[t]}, {t, t0, tend}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {gridt}, MeshStyle -> Red]` We'll see the values at grid are accurate. Since my primary method doesn't involve technique like self-adaptive step choosing, I'm afraid it's not suitable to achieve what you want. (In principle a rather dense grid should help, but that's too expensive. )

Comment: It is not clear why do you try to compare `g[t]` and not solution himself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several numerical methods to solve fractional PDE. In this case the best one could be implicit difference scheme described in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42967-019-00023-y). The implementation is not so difficult compare to `pdetode`. We have

```
L = 1; tend = 1/50; dx = L/80; xgrid = Range[0, L, dx]; nn = 
 Length[xgrid];
M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
    DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
wA = Table[wa[i][t], {i, nn}];
w2 = M2 . wA;
eq = Table[D[wA[[i]], t] == w2[[i]], {i, 2, nn - 1}];
bc = {wA[[1]] == 0, wA[[-1]] == 0};
ic = Table[
  wA[[i]] == Sin[Pi  xgrid[[i]]] /. t -> 0, {i, 2, nn - 1}]; icn = 
 Join[ic, bc /. t -> 0];
eqn = Join[eq, D[bc, t]]; var1 = D[wA, t];

sol[q_, nt1_] := 
  Module[{f, ff, vec, mat, cj, vij, dt, m, grid, nt, 
    eqq}, {vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, var1];
   f = Inverse[mat // N] . (-vec);
   dt = tend/nt1; m = Length[f]; grid = Range[0, tend, dt]; 
   nt = Length[grid]; vij = Table[wA[[i]], {t, grid}, {i, m}];
   ff = Table[ f, {t, grid}];
   cj = Table[(j + 1)^(1 - q) - j^(1 - q), {j, nt}]; 
   eqAll = Flatten[
     Table[dt^(-q)/
         Gamma[2 - q] (vij[[n, i]] - vij[[n - 1, i]] + 
          Sum[(vij[[n - j + 1, i]] - vij[[n - j, i]]) cj[[j]], {j, 1, 
            n - 1}]) - ff[[n, i]], {n, 2, nt}, {i, m}]];
   varALL = Flatten[vij];
   so = FindRoot[
     Join[Table[eqAll[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqAll]}], icn], 
     Table[{varALL[[i]], .1}, {i, Length[varALL]}], 
     Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}, 
     MaxIterations -> 1000]; so];
```

Note, that solver `sol[]` is universal one. We can use it to solve nonlinear problems as well. Example of usage

```
sol01 = sol[1/10, 20];
```

Visualization

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[{t, xgrid[[i]], wA[[i]] /. sol01}, {i, nn}, {t, 
    Range[0, tend, tend/20]}] // Evaluate, PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "y"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can compare numerical solution with exact solution

```
y = Function[{t, x}, 
  MittagLefflerE[1/10, -\[Pi]^2 t^(1/10)] Sin[\[Pi] x]]
     
Table[Show[
  Plot[y[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabel -> N[t]], 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xgrid, wA /. sol01}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]], {t, Range[0, tend, tend/20]}]
```

[image: Figure 2]
We see a large discrepancies on first two steps. But after that numerical solution comes to exact solution. Unfortunately this is common problem for all implicit schemas described in the paper sited. This scheme has an order $2-\alpha$ in $L_2$ norm. We can improve this code using higher order difference scheme from the paper cited

```
(*Caputo numerical derivative with order of accuracy 3-\[Alpha]*)
a[j_][q_] := (j + 1)^(1 - q) - j^(1 - q);
b[j_][q_] := ((j + 1)^(2 - q) - j^(2 - q))/(2 - 
      q) - ((j + 1)^(1 - q) + j^(1 - q))/2;
(*Fractional equations numerical solution*)       
sol12[q_, nt_] := 
  Module[{f, ff, vec, mat, c, vij, dt, m, grid, eqA}, {vec, mat} = 
    CoefficientArrays[eqn, var1];
   f = Inverse[mat // N] . (-vec);
   dt = tend/(nt - 1); m = Length[f]; grid = Range[0, tend, dt]; 
   vij = Table[wA[[i]], {t, grid}, {i, m}];
   ff = Table[f, {t, grid}]; eqA = Table[0, {nt - 1}, {m}];
   Do[Do[c[0] = If[n == 1, 1, a[0][q] + b[0][q]]; 
      If[n >= 2, 
       Do[c[j] = a[j][q] + b[j][q] - b[j - 1][q];, {j, 1, n - 2}]; 
       c[n - 1] = a[n - 1][q] - b[n - 2][q]]; 
      eqA[[n - 1, i]] = 
       dt^(-q)/Gamma[2 - q] (c[0] vij[[n, i]] - c[n - 1] vij[[1, i]] -
            Sum[(c[n - j - 1] - c[n - j]) vij[[j, i]], {j, 1, 
             n - 1}]) - ff[[n, i]];, {n, 2, nt}];, {i, m}];
   varALL = Flatten[vij]; eqAll = Flatten[eqA];
   {res, {evx}} = 
    Reap[FindRoot[
      Join[Table[eqAll[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqAll]}], icn], 
      Table[{varALL[[i]], .1}, {i, Length[varALL]}], 
      Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}, 
      MaxIterations -> 1000, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[varALL]]]; 
   L2 = Table[
     Norm[evx[[k]][[1]] - evx[[k + 1]][[1]]], {k, 
      Length[evx] - 1}]; {res, evx, L2}];

sol012 = sol12[1/10, 21][[1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Table[Show[
  Plot[y[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabel -> N[t]], 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xgrid, wA /. sol012}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]], {t, Range[0, tend, tend/20]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks!