# How to validate the solution of a system of integro-differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I have successfully solved a system of integro-differential equations.

The system is

```
Eq1 = x1'[t] == (1 - 3/2*Exp[t]) x1[t] + 1/2 Exp[3*t] x2[t] + 
   Integrate[1/4 Exp[-t + 2*s - x1[s]^2] x1[s], {s, 0, t}];

Eq2 = x2'[t] == (-Exp[3*t]) x1[t] - 2 Exp[t] x2[t] + 
   Integrate[1/4 Exp[-t + 2*s - x2[s]^2] x2[s], {s, 0, t}]
```

Now following @J.M. [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/how-to-plot-and-solve-the-numerical-solution-of-a-integro-differential-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1), I convert the above system to a system of ODE's, like this,

```
nEq1 = x1'[t] == (1 - 3/2*Exp[t]) x1[t] + 1/2 Exp[3*t] x2[t] + Exp[-t]*x10[t]
nEq1x10 = x10'[t] == 1/4 Exp[2*t - x1[t]^2] x1[t]
nEq2 = x2'[t] == (-Exp[3*t]) x1[t] - 2 Exp[t] x2[t] + Exp[-t]*x20[t]
nEq2x20 = x20'[t] == 1/4 Exp[2*t - x2[t]^2]*x2[t]
```

With the initial conditions

```
ics = {x1[0] == 1, x10[0] == 0, x2[0] == 2, x20[0] == 0};
```

Now solving the converted system using `NDSolve`

```
sys = Join[{nEq1, nEq1x10, nEq2, nEq2x20}, ics];
sol = NDSolve[sys, {x1[t], x2[t]}, {t, 0, 4}];
```

Finally, plotting the results,

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

My question is, how we can validate the solutions?

Comment: You want to check the validity of the solution with respect to the orginal `Eq1`, Eq2`? How did you calculate the ODE system?

Comment: @Feyre That's right!, if possible? I converted the integral to a differential and end up with two extra  odes.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `NDSolve` is quite robust for solving IVP of ODE(s), so the result will be correct as long as the deduction of ODEs is correct. BTW you can deduce `x10'[t]` with `D[Integrate[1/4 Exp[-t + 2*s - x2[s]^2] x2[s]/Exp[-t], {s, 0, t}]
 , t]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the two sides of `Eq1` and `Eq2`.

If the ODE is valid, the two sides of each equation are equal.
You can break up the equations into parts.
For the right hand side`Eq1`, the first two parts will be:

```
sol1p1 = ((1 - 3/2*Exp[t]) x1[t] /. sol) + 1/2 Exp[3*t] x2[t] /. sol
```

In the interim, plotting these with `x1[t]` becomes:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{D[x1[t] /. sol, 
    t], sol1p1}], {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Already very close.

[image]

You need to add a variable replacement for the integral:

```
sol1p2[tt_] := 
 NIntegrate[
   1/4 Exp[-t + 2*s - (x1[s] /. (sol /. t -> s))^2] x1[s] /. (sol /. 
      t -> s), {s, 0, t}] /. t -> tt
```

And plotting it:

```
Plot[sol1p2[t], {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Adding them together, and subtracting the original lhs of `Eq1`:

```
Plot[sol1p5[t][[1]] + sol1p1[[1]] - D[x1[t] /. sol, t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

And some values:

```
Table[(sol1p5[t][[1]] + sol1p1[[1]] - D[x1[t] /. sol, t]) /. 
  t -> tt, {tt, 0, 4}]
```

> `{{0.}, {0.0000332613}, {-4.37529*10^-6}, {-0.0000395381}, \
>   {-0.0000143361}}`

Which are very close to zero, as we would expect.

You can do the same for `Eq2`.