# This integro-differential equation will be able to generate a graph? Use the MATLA

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

How to create a graph?
when l = 6 , h = 0.1
[image]

Comment: @zhk .This is not an exact duplicate. This not help to solve https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137017/how-to-validate-the-solution-of-a-system-of-integro-differential-equations

Comment: You can use a `Laplace Transform` to this equation and at the and find solution with numerical `Inverse Laplace Transform`.